# Error while saving File in ubuntu 12.04 guest OS

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 as the guest in virtual box with windows 8.1 as host.

Whenever I try to save a text file I have been editing I get this error message on my first try at saving the file.

```
"Could not save file /thedirectory/thefilename
Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy."
```

Is this a Virtualbox problem or an Ubuntu problem? How can I get it to save correctly first time?

**NOTE :** this happens in the shared folder - not in the rest of Ubuntu hence it  might be a virtual box problem.

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```
//shareIP/sharedFolder mountpoint smbfs rw,umask=777,uid=linuxUID,username='windowsUsername',password='windowsPassword',auto 0 0
```

Comment: See this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/537799/save-in-gedit-without-in-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment735502_537799