# save in gedit without ~ in virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, gedit

How can I save in gedit whilst using ubuntu 12.04 in virtualbox into a shared folder without ~ being added to the end of the file name?

If I try the answers suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix) then I cannot save at all. Instead I get the error:

```
Could not save the file /filepath/morefilepath/filename
Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy
```

Comment: Do you want to save in a shared folder?

Comment: Yes. I should add that to the question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in gedit when writing to a place where its locks don't work.

Comment: Any thoughts would be welcome even if I need a new file editor. I have no clue about Linux.

Comment: I think that it is normal. Are you sure that you have access to read file system you talk about..

Comment: @MURATSPLAT Definitely, Save As works when I use a different file name. Save does not.

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug for a long time (Nautilus and Gedit):
[Inability to overwrite files in shared folders from Nautilus and other means](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9203)

There are a few more bug reports /tickets for virtualbox and gnome. Just google around. Seems that this issue won't be fixed...